# Issue with singleton pattern in python

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I am using a python class with **Singleton** pattern to get different types of benefits e.g

- To limit concurrent access to a shared resource.
- To create a global point of access for a resource.
- To create just one instance of a class, throughout the lifetime of a program.

But now having some issues with that also, so let me know how can I fix this issue but get the benefits of the **Singleton** pattern mentioned above. ***Note:*** Here I am using python zeep for SOAP calls.

**Sample Code:**

```
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from shared import Singleton
import zeep

class MySoapClient(metaclass=Singleton):
    """MyFancySoapClient"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        user: str = "username",
        password: str = "password",
        wsdl: str = "wsdl_url_goes_here",
    ):
        self._history = HistoryPlugin()
        self._soap_client = zeep.Client(wsdl, plugins=[self._history])



    def methodA():
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceA(
            body
        )
        return resp
    
    def methodB():
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceB(
            body
        )
        return resp

    def methodC(request_proxy_url):
        self._soap_client.transport.session.proxies = {"https": request_proxy_url}
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceE(
            body
        )
        return resp
    
    def methodD():
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceC(
            body
        )
        return resp

    def methodE():
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceD(
            body
        )
        return resp

client = MySoapClient()
client.methodA()
client.methodB()
client.methodC("https://example.com")  <---- after this call it modifies the '_soap_client' attribute
client.methodD()  
client.methodE()
```

That's why `methodD()` and `methodE()` get affected because of added `self._soap_client.transport.session.proxies`, actually I need to set proxy URL only for `methodC()` but due to singleton it propagates the updated attribute value to `mothodD()` and `methodE()` also. Finally make my `methodD()` and `methodE()` fails because SOAP call inside those method doesn't need use to proxy.

Comment: So you're trying to use singleton pattern, but you actually need multiple instances of the client with different behaviours... ok.  Within your current paradigm you need to capture the initial value of `self._soap_client.transport.session.proxies` before changing it in `methodC`, then swap it back before returning from `methodC`.

Comment: Thanks  for the comment. What if from different place I call methodA, methodB, methodD or methodaE before completing methodC?

Comment: as long as you do all the pre-setup and post-cleanup within `methodC` it should work (as long as your program is single threaded)

Comment: @Anentropic you can  post an answer.Also if other design pattern help to achieve above benefits you can share that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your methodC as:

```py
    def methodC(request_proxy_url):
        original_proxies = self._soap_client.transport.session.proxies
        self._soap_client.transport.session.proxies = {"https": request_proxy_url}
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceE(
            body
        )
        self._soap_client.transport.session.proxies = original_proxies
        return resp
```

(and do similar for any other methods which need to modify the set up of the `self._soap_client` instance before making the request)

I am a bit skeptical of enforcing the singleton pattern, rather than just creating a global var in a module and importing that from everywhere... but that is just personal taste and no relation to your issue.

Knowing the nature of SOAP APIs I expect the `zeep.Client` instance is quite a heavy object so it totally makes sense to try to avoid having multiple instances if you can avoid it.

If you use a multi threaded platform (like e.g. Python with `gevent`) then you have to be careful to avoid global vars which mutate their shared state, like this MySoapClient now does.

An alternative would be for it to maintain a small number of distinct `zeep.Client` instances, and for each methodA, methodC etc to use the appropriate _soap_client instance. Something like:

```py
class MySoapClient(metaclass=Singleton):
    """MyFancySoapClient"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        user: str = "username",
        password: str = "password",
        wsdl: str = "wsdl_url_goes_here",
        request_proxy_url: str = "default value",
    ):
        self._history = HistoryPlugin()
        self._soap_client = zeep.Client(wsdl, plugins=[self._history])
        self._soap_client_proxied = zeep.Client(wsdl, plugins=[self._history])
        self._soap_client_proxied.transport.session.proxies = {"https": request_proxy_url}

    def methodB():
        resp = self._soap_client.ServiceB(
            body
        )
        return resp

    def methodC(request_proxy_url):
request_proxy_url}
        resp = self._soap_client_proxied.ServiceE(
            body
        )
        return resp

   # etc
```

Comment: Actually I was thinking the same way that you shared for rewriting methodC. Thanks for full answer though 

Comment: I have found an issue with `pre-setup and post-cleanup within` pattern that's why adopting the later approach with `normal` and `proxied` zeep client.